# How to account for dynamic rows in a CSS Grid setup?

Tags: html, css, vue.js, vue-component, css-grid

My home dashboard has a general structure of `div` elements piled one on top of each other (each of them is screen-wide and provides different kind of information).

I manage the height of the blocks though CSS Grid: the whole application is `min-height: 100vh;` and the rows are `auto` except for one which is `1fr`. It works great.

I am now faced with the case where one of the lines is dynamically present or absent. This is because it is actually a Vue component, displayed conditionally with `v-if`. The problem is that the CSS part is not aware of its presence and `grid-template-rows` is fixed. This leads to the wrong rows being `auto` and `1fr` when it is toggled.

**How to fix that?**

One way I can think of would be to force the presence of the component in a way where CSS would count it as a row. Right now I see this element as `<!----> == $0` in Dev Tools when it is off.

Another one would be to "describe" the columns template rather than have a fixed list. Something along the lines of "*use `auto` as much as possible, then `1fr` and one `auto`*"

---

**The two code fragments below simulate my problem.**

The first one is the case where all elements are visible

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#footer {
  align-self: end;
}

div {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>this line is always visible</div>
  <div>this one is toggled - here it is visible</div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer</div>
</div>
```

The one below is the same code, but with the second line toggled (commented out here, disabled via `v-if` in the real code). See how it affect the footer which is not at the bottom anymore because the CSS has not changed (= did not adapt to a dissapearing row)

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#footer {
  align-self: end;
}

div {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>this line is always visible</div>
  <!-- <div>this one is toggled - here it is not visible anymore </div> -->
  <div id="footer">this is the footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code? so we can see the structure, the number of element, the template, etc

Comment: @TemaniAfif: OK, got an idea to minimize the code and the examples reflect my problem now.

Comment: Um...Why not use flexbox for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One idea is to explicitely define the row for the footer to always use the last one:

```css
#app {
  display: grid;
  min-height: 100vh;
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}

#footer {
  align-self: end;
  grid-row:-1;
}

div {
  border-style: dashed;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>this line is always visible</div>
  <div>this one is toggled - here it is visible</div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer</div>
</div>

<div id="app">
  <div>this line is always visible</div>
  <!--<div>this one is toggled - here it is visible</div>-->
  <div id="footer">this is the footer</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah, this is a good idea. I was looking for this kind of relative counting but did not know it existed. How are the `auto` in `grid-template-rows` interpreted then - when the amount of elements in `grid-template-rows` does not match the actual number of rows? (when the toggled row is off)

Comment: @WoJ the middle `auto` will get computed to 0 but you will always have 3 rows and the second one empty since no item is placed inside it

Answer (score 0):

The `CSS grid` system isn't the best for dynamic rows/columns. It's at its best when you know what the layout will be ahead of time.

However, there some things you can do.

**Option 1**

You can define `grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;` using inline styles (within the parent element, and control using `javascript`.

So, in this case:

```html
<div id="app" style="grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;">
```

And as the number of rows change, you alter the value of the style.

```html
<div id="app" style="grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;">
```

**Option 2**

Define several classes ahead of time and switch to the appropriate class based on the number of rows:

```css
.rows-2
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr;
}

.rows-3
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr;
}
```

```html
<div id="app" class="rows-2/3">
```

Both these solutions will require some javascript to adjust to the required grid layout.